Can't load numpy when installed through Anaconda
I am trying to run the vaex module which requires Python 3.6 and, apparently, a conda install rather than a pip install. I don't really know what I'm doing here, but I went ahead and installed Anaconda and created a new conda environment through the Anaconda prompt using conda create -n research_project_conda python=3.6 vaex numpy pandas scikit-learn. That went without any problems, and I can load the environment in VSCode. However, when I try to run a script using this environment I get the error below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marij\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2024.22.0-win32-x64\python_files\python_server.py", line 133, in exec_user_input
    retval = callable_(user_input, user_globals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.6 from "C:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_conda\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I tried to add some paths to my PATH according to this thread, but it still doesn't work. Again, I'm a bit of a noob at this. Does anyone know what may be the issue?

Do you have installed the required version of NumPy (check with conda search numpy) and Python (python -V)?

@Thinkr when I run python -V it returns 3.16.13, and conda search numpy returns a big list that includes several instances of 1.19.2 in conda-forge and pkgs/main

The paths you added have anaconda3 or miniconda3 in it? have you checked that they exist on your computer?

@rehaqds yea I couldn't find it in the same location, but found the folders under my user/anaconda3/...

strange, the error message quotes .../miniconda3 not anaconda3

It seems that anaconda wasn't fully downloaded, miniconda "is a free, miniature installation of Anaconda Distribution that includes only conda, Python, the packages they both depend on, and a small number of other useful packages." (Miniconda - Anaconda Docs) Perhaps it is worth trying to install anaconda instead?

Did you find a solution?
